# Techniques to check the regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

> Consider the function $$f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} , \ f (x,y,z) = \cos^{2} {(x)} \cdot \sinh ^{2}  {(y)} -z^{2} +c$$
>
> For which values of $c$ is the zero-set of $f$ a regular surface?

---

By definition, a subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a *regular surface* if for each point $p \in M$, there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a map $x: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ onto $V \cap M$, such that

$x$ is differentiable;

$x: U \to V \cap M$ is a homeomorphism;

Each map $x: U \to M$ is a regular patch.

---

I set  $f (x,y,z) = \cos^{2} (x)  \sinh^{2} (y) -z^{2} +c$ , then $\cos^{2} (x) \cdot \sinh^{2}(y) -z^{2} = -c$.

Also, set $\nabla f = \left( -2 \sin (x) \cos(x) \sinh ^{2} (y) \ 2\cos^{2}(x) \  \sinh (y)  \cosh(y) \  -2z \right) = 0 $ to get the critical points $(x,0,0)$, where $x$ can be any real number.

But what's next? How can I apply the definition to such problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lay terms, regularity means 1) we don't want edges; 2) we don't want creases; 3) we don't want two parts of surfaces to be glued in points or along lines (no self intersections).

The given surfaces bifurcates at point $c=0$, since when $c\le 0$, $z$ can be anything including $0$; when $c>0$, possible $z$ values are disjoint ($z\le-\sqrt c \cap z\ge\sqrt c$). That gives as 3 cases to consider:

1. $c>0$

As was said, $z$ values are disjoint (and symmetric), so we only need to consider one part of the surface $z>0$:
$$ z = \sqrt{c+\cos^2x \sinh^2 y}
$$
That function is defined for all $x,y$ (no edges); cannot touch the other surface (no glued surfaces); and we need to get sure about creases. We take the parametrization of patch $x,y$ and find Jacobian:
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\z'_x&z'_y\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since derivatives can be defined for all $x,y$ the rank of Jacobian is 2 and every patch is regular (no creases).

2. $c<0$

You can show that your surfaces doesn't intersect planes $y=0$ and $x=\pi/2+\pi n$, so we can consider only part where $y>0$, $-\pi/2 < x < \pi/2$ (other parts are symmetric):
$$
y=\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{z^2-c}{\cos^2x}}
$$
Using the same arguments we show that there are no edges, creases and touching surfaces.

3. $c=0$

Consider a neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$. There is a surface $z=|\cos x\sinh y|$ and surface $z=-|\cos x\sinh y|$ and they are glued at the point $(0,0)$